# Could plugging a dishwasher into an outlet cause it to not dry as well?

Tags: wiring, dishwasher

I see a post saying it is OK to plug a built-in dish washer into an outlet.  I have had our dish washer plugged into an outlet for years.  The first dish washer never dried well.  I thought it was the dish washer.  I bought a new Bosch dish washer a couple years ago that is supposed to wash super well and dry well.  However, it does not dry well, at all!  I am thinking maybe the outlet being only 15A does not provide enough current for the dishwasher to heat the drying element well enough.  Therefore not drying well.

Thoughts?  I think I am going to hard wire it and see if that helps.

Comment: The 15A rated receptacle is not limiting the current to 15A. That rating is just there to say that if it passes 15, you're going to burn up the receptacle. Seeing as how it's ran so far without starting a fire, switching it over won't change a thing.

Answer (score 1):

If your circuit breaker isn't tripping when the old or new dishwasher ran a full cycle, then hardwiring won't change a single thing. Check that your drain hose is clear & run up to above the sink trap or underside of the countertop.

There should be quite a forceful stream of water visible in the garbage disposal or sink drain. If not & you have an Air Gap atop the sink, then take the cap off the Air gap (dishwasher off) & clear all debris. You'll need to snake something down the hose leading into the garbage disposal or sink drain until you can see it come out in either. Correct any hose under the sink to be as inclined as possible above it's connection so future flow-back is eliminated.

And, especially check that the bottom of the dishwasher's inside grate or strainer is clear...if clear glass ever broke in there you really won't notice it blocking the water exit. Also, if you wash food product jars without completely removing labels, they will gum up the works quite badly & quickly.

All this should get you back in tip top shape. A new dishwasher doesn't fix an old or worsening clog.

Comment: Just backing up Iggy on this one.  If it is getting electricity, the outlet is working.  Changing the outlet for a hard-wiring job isn't going to give it better / more drying capabilities.  Now, if the wiring is bad / the electricity is tripping, that's a different story.

Comment: Thanks. It's nice to verify I'm not totally nuts once in awhile.

Answer (score 0):

The drying is electric and takes a lot of power, so it really tests the performance of your wiring.  If you have any problems with the wiring or outlet, heat is being made in your walls instead of in your dishwasher.  This can start a fire, and breakers aren't 100% effective at oreventing this, so it's worth looking for.

I would get a Kill-a-Watt, which is a voltage and current tester sold at home improvement shops like Menards, and plug the dishwasher through it in a way that lets you read the display.  Have it show you voltage.  Learn normal voltage with the dryer off (near 120v) and watch it during the drying cycle.  If it drops significantly, stop the dishwasher and report the numbers back here.